# How to set the product can not be seen in new products block but still can be seen on the category page?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, new-products

I try to add a product rather than as a new product but still be accessible from other pages such as categories or related products. In the admin panel, `Set Product as New from Date` and `Set Product as New to Date` has been filled in correctly. But the product still exists in the block of new products on the home page.

**EDITED**.

File edited from `public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php`

This the code :

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel("catalog/product_collection');
$collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            // this is the code i've edited
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_new_product', array('eq' => 1)) 
            ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'asc')
            ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
            ->setCurPage(1);
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: You need to supply how your new products block is workin, more specifically how you get the collection of said products.

Comment: Provide more info about your `new products block `

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new product attribute (Yes/No type) like `is_from_new_product_block` to differentiate/filter product from others.

You can use this attribute to get product collection as `new product block`, like:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_from_new_product_block',1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
```

Also you can filter this collection (for from and to dates, etc...) as per you requirement as a `new product block`

Comment: thank's for reply.. Can you tell me which files can be edited?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can assign product to a **Category** which is not displayed on front end.

And Product will be visible in `New Products`.